# Удаление созданных с помощью new объектов

Tags: c++, qt

Народ, прошу помощи. Вроде простой вопрос, но ничего полезного при поиске решения не нашел. Короче, есть программа, которая выводит таблицы с возможностью перемещения их по `QGraphicsItem`. Каждая таблица - это объект, объекты создаются в цикле при помощи new. Также при перемещении таблицы отправляется сигнал, и есть слот, который сохраняет измененное положение таблицы.

Так вот, в определенный момент при нажатии на кнопку нужно перерисовать все эти таблицы. Я очищаю сцену scene->clear(), и заново вызываю функцию, в которой создаются объекты. И программа после нескольких нажатий кнопки, вызывающей отрисовку, вылетает. Подозреваю, что это связано с тем, что во время перевызова функции я не удаляю созданные объекты.

Так ли это, и если так, то как получше будет их удалить, учитывая, что они создаются в цикле, и их количество может меняться в зависимости от входных данных?

Comment: Включаете отладчик и начинаете удалять куски кода, пока падения не прекратятся. Таким образом Вы найдёте потенциально проблемный кусок кода. Когда кода станет мало, а вопросы всё равно останутся, тогда можно создать минимальный пример и с ним прийти уже сюда.

Comment: Просто удаляйте ненужные, в чем проблема?

Comment: Согласно документации `clear` удаляет объекты на сцене и руками удалять их не надо. Проблема где-то в другом месте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#clear

Comment: При создании добавляйте указатели на таблицы в список и когда нужно будет их удалить, то пройдитесь по списку и сделайте delete